# How to turn off vscode adding autocompletion "={}" after selecting a suggestion

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

working on a react native project here using VSCode. It appears than when a suggestion is selected:
[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tso8u.png)
It adds this `={}` after:
[After selecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGuA6.png).

This gets annoying, as you would expect it to only populate `key={innerIdx}` instead of `key={innerIdx={}}`. I tried to turn off and on a bunch of stuff in the settings, but no luck.

Anyone knows how to solve this, without turning off the suggestion, just to kill the behaviour that adds that extra `={}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off specific suggestions follow the instruction below:

1. find your defaultSettings.json via Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON).
2. with ctrl+f search this : "typescript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "auto"
3. then change it from auto to none

here is the full reference for all attributes in vs code.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

// Preferred style for JSX attribute completions.

//  - auto: Insert `={}` or `=""` after attribute names based on the prop type.

//  - braces: Insert `={}` after attribute names.

//  - none: Only insert attribute names.

"typescript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "auto",

you must change it to **none.**

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Been looking for the name of the setting!